# Retrieve data from MongoDB/Flask and display it in an HTML page using Jinja2

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, jinja2

I am trying to retrieve data associated with a user ID and show it in an HTML page. I am using MongoDB with Flask (PyMongo) for my backend. This is something new for me so please ask for more clarification if needed, but I will try my best to explain.

I have a User class:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user.upper()
        # self.id = id

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return self.user
        # return self.id

    @staticmethod
    def validate_login(password_hash, password):
        return check_password_hash(password_hash, password)
```

After the user successfully logs in, I believe the following code is used to return user associated data.

```
lm = LoginManager()
@lm.user_loader
def load_user(user):
    u = app.config['MY_USERS'].find_one({"_id": user})
    if not u:
        return None
    print "\n"
    print "my ID is " + str(u['id'])
    print "\n"
    return User(u['user'])
```

I can see the "ID" of my user in the console. But I am unable to show that ID in my HTML page. I am able to see the username in my HTML using `Hello, {{ current_user.user }}`, but I am unable to replicate this technique for the ID.

How can I achieve this? Or is the correct way to send an AJAX request once the user logs in and get the user associated data in JSON format?

Edit: More details.

Here is the code that renders the HTML page for both the `login.html` and `dashboard.html` that the user sees once logged in.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        user = app.config['MY_USERS'].find_one({"_id": form.user.data.upper()})
        if user and User.validate_login(user['password'], form.password.data):
            user_obj = User(user['_id'])
            login_user(user_obj)
            flash("Logged in successfully!", category='success')
            return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for("dashboard"))
        flash("Wrong username or password!", category='error')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

Once logged in, `Hello, {{ current_user.user }}` greets the user in `dashboard.html`.

Comment: Where is the code you use to render the HTML template?

Comment: @franklin Just added more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by modifying my `User` class. Here is what I did, but I am not sure if this is the correct method.

I added the following in the `User` class to get the user ID:

```
def get_id(self):
    return self.user
    return self.id
```

Then modified `def __init__` in the same file to include the ID:

```
def __init__(self, user, id):
    self.user = user.upper()
    self.id = id
```

In the `load_user`, I modified the return to include the ID: `return User(u['user'], u['id'])`

Then in the HTML what I was trying to do worked, which is using Jinja2 to show the ID: `{{ current_user.id }}`